# How to deny default Google Chrome settings in form in html

Tags: html, css

```
.form {
    border: 0;
    background: transparent;
}
```

Afterwards you click on it (you are able to input data), it has orange border. And:

```
.form:focus {
    border: 0;
    background: transparent;
}
```

Doesn't solve this problem. The HTML of itself is:

`<input type="text" class="form" placeholder="Type here"></input>`

Is there a possibility to delete that, thing?

Comment: `</input>` doesn't exist and isn't valid: `<input>` or `<input/>` are valid (same as for img, br or hr for example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for the `outline` css property. `outline: 0` should take care of that highlighting on selection.

Comment: It will not allow me to tick it as correct answer within 12 minutes. But if it will finally allow me, I will. Could you please tell me maybe difference between `outline` and `border`?

Comment: @RikTelner You can accept an answer 15 minutes after your question was posted. But for the difference, `outline` doesn't take up "space" so things won't move within your layout. That makes it perfect to use for input highlighting since it won't affect the visual layout of the page.

Comment: Modifying default outline on focus for some browser is OK. Removing it isn't, it causes a lot of problems to some users. Please see http://www.outlinenone.com for that matter

Comment: @StevenV Is it something like border with `position: absolute;` effect?

Comment: @RikTelner Similar. But you don't have the ability to position the outline. Just that outline's height and width does not affect the positions of elements around it.

Comment: @StevenV Thank you. I finally had opportunity to tick is as correct answer.

Comment: If you're looking for a way to adjust the "outline" than box-shadow in lieu of outline is great for exactly that reason, it too doesn't affect the positioning of the field but has many more styling options.